# How do I boot windows?

Tags: boot, wubi, windows-vista

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 wubi but am a bit unnerved by the fact that all of my windows files and settings are not visible to me and I can't figure out how to boot windows.  Can someone help a guy out who is in over his head?

Comment: The first reboot goes straight into Ubuntu to complete the install. Reboot and you should see the option to boot either - default is Windows (keep it that way). PS Your files can be found under `/host`

Answer (score 2):

*This was answered in [a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231622/how-do-i-boot-windows#comment286222_231622) by [bcbc](https://askubuntu.com/users/14916/bcbc) (slightly modified here).*

The first reboot goes straight into Ubuntu to complete the install. Reboot and you should see the option to boot either. The default is Windows (keep it that way).

In the Ubuntu system, your Windows files can be found under `/host`.